# Taylor series with $x^{n^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

How can we find, if it exists, a closed form of
$$A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^3}$$
I can't find any recursive relation for the coefficients ($a_m=1$ if $m$ is a cube $a_n=0$ otherwise). There is not much more to try (that I know of) so I'm completely lost here. Maybe there is no closed form expression. If we truncate the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^mx^{n^3}$$
what can we do?

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt there is an expression for this series in terms of rational or trancenentol functions (exp, trigonometric and the lot). Here is something that may be of interest to you nonetheless: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function

Comment: I don't believe this series has any particular name. It is notable though that the case of $n^2$ in the exponent instead of $n^3$ appears in number theory sometimes and is related to the Jacobi theta function.

Comment: As pointed out by Oliver Diaz, $A(x)$ demonstrates lacunary behavior that elementary functions are lacking. So $A(x)$ would not correspond to any of familiar functions that you know.

Comment: To refer to what @SimplyBeautifulArt said, the answer  mentions the _Jacobi theta function_.

Comment: Because of hair-triggered closure, an answer for the specific question here is posted to the general question [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3739169/123905).

Answer (score 0):

If you consider  $$A_k(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^k}$$ there is nothing to do if $k>2$ except computing the numerical values for $-1 < x <1$.

For $k=3$, it is "amazing" (at least to me) that the summation goes through a minimum value close to $0.35$ when $x\sim -0.744$ and that, for $-0.5 \leq x \leq 0.5$, it is "almost" a straight line $(\sim 1+x)$.